# php cut string from end of string

Tags: php, string, strsplit

I have a string like any of the following:

```
$str = 'A001';
$str = 'B001';
$str = 'AB001';
$str = 'B0015';
....
$str = '001A';
```

I want to keep only 3 characters from the end of each string.

My code is like this:

```
 $code = str_split($str);
 $code = $code[1].$code[2].$code[3];
```

But it works for specific cases, but not for general ones! How I can get it for general ones?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: `$code = '001'`,`$code = '001'` , `...`;

Answer (score 2):

> I want to keep every 3 character from end of string

Simply Use **[substr](http://www.php.net/substr)**

```
echo substr($str,-3);    // Last 3 characters
```

Second parameter to this function is **start**, and according to the Manual

> If start is negative, the returned string will start at the start'th character from the end of string.

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/STsGuG2c)**

Answer (score 0):

Use [**sbstr()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
echo substr($str,-3);//get last 3 char char
```

Or try:

```
echo $str[strlen($str)-3].$str[strlen($str)-2].$str[strlen($str)-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function.

All you need to do is to pass the string, and tell it where you cut the string off. If you want to cut the string off from end, you have to provide the value in negative.

```
substr($str, -3);
// The third argument is optional, which specifies the length of the returned string.
```